# Phonegap display differences

Tags: html, css, cordova, webkit

I build an app with Phonegap. My problem is that in the 2.2 version of android an input field is centering correctly but in the higher versions the input field is displayed at the left side. For me this makes no sense because i thought phonegap is displayed the same way on all devices and that phonegap works like an webkit browser. What did i understand false about it?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your problem.  Screenshots, bits of code, etc.

Comment: PhoneGap uses the webkit rendering engine of the Android system. Different versions of android have different versions of webkit, and the rendering might be slightly different.